# hmac length attack extension python

Tags: python, security, cryptography, hmac

I am a student and i am struggling with performing a length extension attack on a poorly implementation python HMAC code below

i have been given the following fake recorded message

```
581b464951404558504f071e7359100d00|Delete all files on c: and d: and e:
```

and would like to append something like "and install linux" or something to the end of the code.

```
megaBlockSize=128
def strToNum(inp):
    """Takes a sequence of bytes and makes a number"""
    out=0
    for i in inp:
        out=out<<8
        out^=ord(i)
    return out

def numToStr(inp):
    """Take a number and make a sequence of bytes in a string"""
    out=""
    while inp!=0:
        out=chr(inp & 255)+out
        inp=inp>>8
    return out

def cueh_hash_2(inp, blockSize):
    """ CUEH Hash Function v 2.0 
    Returns given-length hash of any string input or stringable input
    Uses given number of bits, must be multiple of 8
    """
    if blockSize%8!=0 or blockSize<=0:
        raise Exception("Block size must be a multiple of 8")
    inp=str(inp) #Make sure we have a string
    while (len(inp)%(blockSize/8)!=0):
        inp=" "+inp #Pad it if we need to
    val=0<<blockSize #Our accumulator
    for pos in range(0,len(inp),blockSize/8): #Now in blocks of the rigth size...
        for pos2 in range(blockSize/8):
            tval=ord(inp[pos2+pos])
            tval=tval<<(blockSize-pos2*8)
            val=val^tval
    return val

def cueh_hmac_2(key, message, blockSize):
    """Outputs a hash-based digest of the message and secret key combo"""
    key=str(key)
    message=str(message)
    if len(key)>blockSize/8:
        key=numToStr(cueh_hash_2(key,blockSize)) #Keys are shortened to blocksize
    while len(key)<blockSize/8:
        key+="#" #Keys are padded with spaces if they're too short
    return cueh_hash_2(key+message,blockSize)


def main():
    print "Testing hash: %06x"%cueh_hash_2("ABC\0\0\0",megaBlockSize)

    #Examples of flipping between numbers and strings of bytes
    #Just makes it easier to have "password" style keys
    print "%x"%strToNum("ABC")
    print numToStr((65<<16) + (66<<8) + 67)

    #Now to see it in practice
    secretKey="sswrodfishez"  #This is known by both parties
    authedMessage="ssdsdsdsdsd"


    out=cueh_hmac_2(secretKey,authedMessage, megaBlockSize)
    #Now we have the special verification code that can be used to
    #prove we were the aithor of the message. Anyone else who knows
    #the secret can do the same and compare the values
    dispString="0x%%0%dx|%%s"%(megaBlockSize/16)
    print dispString%(out, authedMessage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()''
```

I have wasted many hours on this.

ANY help is appreciated

Reference [md5 implementation of length extension attack](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks)

Comment: *"I have wasted many hours on this."* - but it seems you haven't gotten anywhere. We're not here to do your homework. The `cueh_hash_2` function is a pretty bad hash function and the `cueh_hmac_2` is not a real HMAC. It shouldn't be too hard to do an attack since it's a simple character-wise XOR.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that your question is by far not clear. 
You seem to have a cryptography problem but you ask about appending a string to the end of another string.

With the risk of oversimplifying your need and if that is the case then why the following code is not enough for you:

```
str1 = "581b464951404558504f071e7359100d00|Delete all files on c: and d: and e: "
str2 = "and install linux"
str3 = str1 + str 2
```

Comment: i am trying to preform a length extension attack where i append str2 and generate the same hash as mentioned in str1

Comment: Oh then it is an algorithmic problem and not python related. You questions seems to be a request for debugging. Not many of them, if at all, get answered. Good luck.